# Why is auto select the last item of listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

When I drop or open multiple file open on listbox by using this rules

Then auto select the last item of listbox.
[image: See]

Follow my code:

Xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox4" Background="Salmon"   BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Drop="listbox4_Drop"  >
</ListBox>
```

Xaml.cs:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> fileDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();   

private void load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.DefaultExt = ".mp3";
    ofd.Filter = "All|*.*";
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    Nullable<bool> result = ofd.ShowDialog();
    if (result == true)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < ofd.FileNames.Length; i++)
        {
            var filePath = ofd.FileNames[i];
            var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            fileDictionary.Add(fileName, filePath);
            listbox4.Items.Add(fileName);
            listbox4.SelectedItem = fileName;
        }
    }
}

    private void listbox4_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {

            string[] droppedFilePaths =
                e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];

            foreach (string droppedFilePath in droppedFilePaths)
            {
                var filePath = droppedFilePath;
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                fileDictionary.Add(fileName, filePath);
                listbox4.Items.Add(fileName);
                listbox4.SelectedItem = fileName;
            }

        }
    }
```

But I want to auto select loaded 1st item on load or drop.

**Note:** I am not talking about like

```
listbox4.SelectedIndex=0;
```

I am talking select 1st item between loaded or drop multiple file.

How this possible?

Comment: The code allows for multiple file selection on the dialog, then it iterates and will always select the last item in that list.  Try this, put a break point on the statement listbox4.SelectedItem = filename and tell us what happens when only 1 file is selected?  Then tell us what happens when more than one file is selected?

Comment: How can I put break point on the statement `listbox4.SelectedItem=filename;`
Same problem has shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set that you have to get the count of total items in the list before load or drop and then after adding the files, set the `SelectedIndex` to the next value. So your code will look something like this :

```
private void load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var listCount = listbox4.Count;
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.DefaultExt = ".mp3";
    ofd.Filter = "All|*.*";
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    Nullable<bool> result = ofd.ShowDialog();
    if (result == true)
    {       
        for (int i = 0; i < ofd.FileNames.Length; i++)
        {
            var filePath = ofd.FileNames[i];
            var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            fileDictionary.Add(fileName, filePath);
            listbox4.Items.Add(fileName);
        }
        listbox4.SelectedIndex = listCount;
    }
}

private void listbox4_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        var listCount = listbox4.Count;
        string[] droppedFilePaths =
            e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];
        foreach (string droppedFilePath in droppedFilePaths)
        {
            var filePath = droppedFilePath;
            var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            fileDictionary.Add(fileName, filePath);
            listbox4.Items.Add(fileName);
        }
        if(droppedFilePaths.Any())
        {
            listbox4.SelectedIndex = listCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But it's ignore that same file add twice at once.
How can I solve?

Comment: I didn't get you. Did you mean if we add a file again it is not working?